# What happened in Calcutta in 1961?

Tags: united-states, military, india, 1960s

I was watching a clip of the **American flag** being raised in **Havana** for the embassy re-opening since closing in 1961. There were some retired Marines there who were there when the flag was taken down. One of them had a hat with something about **Calcutta** in 1961 on his hat.

[image: Men with Hats]

What happened in Calcutta that he would have this on his hat? I don't see anything about a **US military base** in Calcutta nor any battles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would guess that this fellow was stationed at the American consulate general (that is what `AM CON GEN` stands for) in Calcutta between 1961 and 1962.

So to answer your precise question: Probably not much.

Comment: It would make sense. The retired marines at that event were the guys who were present at the flag lowering when the Cuban embassy was closed. They were there back then presumably because they were the marine security detail for the Cuban embassy. So it would make sense that one of those men later had the same type of posting at another embassy.